# strtok() skips first token

Tags: c, strtok

Can't seem to work out why this code is not working.
It should be really straight forward.
From what I have troubleshooted, in the while(token) block the id array is assigned but then when I go to print all the char array's outside the while(token) block the id array displays nothing but all the other array's display their contents.

```
int loadCatData(char* menuFile) {
   char line[MAX_READ];
   char id[ID_LEN];
   char hotCold[MIN_DESC_LEN];
   char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
   char description[MAX_DESC_LEN];
   char delim[2] = "|";
   char lineTemp[MAX_READ];
   int count;
   FILE *mfMenu = fopen(menuFile, "r");

   while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), mfMenu)!=NULL) {
      count = 0;
      printf(line);

      strcpy(lineTemp,line);

      char* token = strtok(lineTemp, delim);

      while (token) {
         printf(token);
         if (count == 0) {
            strcpy(id, token);
         }
         if (count == 1) {
            strcpy(hotCold, token);
         }
         if (count == 2) {
            strcpy(name, token);
         }
         if (count == 3) {
            strcpy(description, token);
         }
         printf("\n");
         token = strtok(NULL, delim);
         count = count + 1;
      }
      printf(id);
      printf(hotCold);
      printf(name);
      printf(description);

   }
   fclose(mfMenu);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the token is copied in the id's array or that it's not empty?

Comment: Anyways, do **else if** in the while loop for the second, third and forth options, because otherwise, every time, even though the body of the "right" **if** statement has already been executed, also the others if statements are going to be checked, but this is not necessary.

Comment: @usar: using `else if` is not really faster than the seemingly-redundant `if` checks, because any reasonable compiler will optimize the code the same way in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are the victim of a buffer overflow error caused by `strcpy`.

What is happening is that the `hotCold` array is too small to hold the data you're filling it with, but `strcpy` doesn't care, nor does it know that there isn't enough room.  So it keeps on writing data into `hotCold` and then runs out of room, then fills up the padding bytes, then fills up `id`.  You just have the unfortunate luck of having the terminating null byte of `hotCold` sitting at the start of `id`.

Switch from using `strcpy` to `strncpy` or `strncat` (which I think is better than `strncpy`).  If you're skeptical of what I'm saying, add a line of code at the end that goes like this:

```
assert (strlen (hotCold) < MIN_DESC_LEN);
```

The other alternative is that the `id` field is being interpreted as a special `printf`-format specifier.  Just in case, replace `printf(id)` with `printf("%s", id)`.

Comment: THANK YOU! you're right, it's the hotCold that's causing the issue. it's only ever a single char so maybe I should try and pass it another way..

Comment: @user3126322 You're welcome.  This is actually a very hard error to track down, the thing that tipped me off though was that you used `strcpy` which is well known for this kind of error.  It was actually being considered for complete removal from the C language at one point.  So as I said in my answer: don't use it, replace it with `strncpy`.

Comment: unfortunately they teach us to use strcpy in the course I'm currently studying which is a bit concerning cause if it's as outdated and bad as you say it is then thats just poor teaching...

Comment: @user3126322 Turn to your teacher and sarcastically say: "if we should use `strcpy` then why aren't we using `gets`?".  `gets` really was removed from the C language, for this very reason.  Also, because of these buffer overflow errors, I could adjust the sample input so that you're program would try to delete every file on your hard drive.  This is known as _smashing the stack_, a very brutal method of hacking.

Comment: `strncpy()` is not so hot either as the destination is not necessarily `'\0'` terminated.  With `str...()` functions, code can determine the length of the operands before function execution and determine is buffer overflow is possible.  With `gets()`, there is no prior test to know if overflow may occur.

Answer (score 1):

```
int loadCatData(const char* menuFile) {
    char id[ID_LEN];
    char hotCold[MIN_DESC_LEN];
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    char description[MAX_DESC_LEN];
    FILE *mfMenu = fopen(menuFile, "r");

    while (fscanf(mfMenu, "%*s|%*s|%*s|%*s",
            sizeof(id), id, sizeof(hotCold), hotCold,
            sizeof(name), name, sizeof(description), description) == 4) {
        printf("%s %s %s %s\n", id, hotCold, name, description);
    }

    fclose(mfMenu);
    return true;
}
```

You should never pass input from outside the program to printf as the first argument.  Imagine if one of the tokens is "%s" and you say printf(token)--that's undefined behavior because you didn't pass a second string to print, and your program will crash if you're lucky.

Comment: +1 for "never pass input from outside the program to printf as the first arg" - so true as it is a great security hole.